# Prove that a graph has a vertex of specific degree with high probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-graphs

> Let $ G_{n,p} $ be a graph with n vertrices, such that each possible edge has a probability of $p$ to exist (there are $ \binom{n}{2} $ possible edges, each one appears in the graph with probability $p$).
> Next, let $p= \frac{d}{n} $ where $d$ is a constant (positive, such that $p$ is well defined). Prove that with high probability, $ G_{n,p}$ contains a vertex of degree of at least $ \left(\ln n\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $.

By "with high probability", I mean that the probability of $ G_{n,p} $ to contain such vertex converge to $1$ when $ n \to \infty$

I dont have an idea right now of how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the second moment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove existence, we'll want to use the second moment method. Here, we will have to notice that the degrees of different vertices are almost independent, and we'll need tight bounds on the tail of the binomial distribution. The proof can be written with the following steps:

1. Define:
   $$\begin{align}
   p&=\frac{d}{n}\gt 0 \\
   K&=\sqrt{\log{n}} \\
   e_{ij}&=\mathbf{1}_{\{\text{ There is an edge between } V_i \text{ and } V_j\}} &\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p) \\
   B_i&=\text{degree of vertex }V_i  &\sim \mathrm{Bin}(n-1,p) \\
   B_i^j & = \text{degree of }V_i \text{ excluding the edge from } V_i \text{ to } V_j & \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n-2,p) \\
   X_{i}&=\mathbf{1}_{\{B_i\ge K\}} \\
   X&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \\
   E[X_i] &= P[B_i\ge K] \\
   \mu_x &= E[X] = n E[X_i] \\
   \ \\
   \end{align} $$

2. Using the relative entropy (or Kullback-Leibler divergence) between the Bernoulli(a) and Bernoulli(p) distribution:
   $$\begin{align} 
   D(a\parallel p) &= a \log\frac{a}{p}+(1-a)\log\frac{1-a}{1-p} \\
   \ 
   \end{align} $$
   with $p=\frac{d}{n}$ and $a=\frac{K}{n}$ we get:
   $$\begin{align} 
   D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel \frac{d}{n}) &= \frac{K}{n}\log\left(\frac{\frac{K}{n}}{\frac{d}{n}}\right)+(1-\frac{K}{n})\log\left(\frac{1-\frac{K}{n}}{1-\frac{d}{n}}\right) \\
   \ \\
   \end{align} $$
3. Using it to express the [chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Additive_form_(absolute_error)) we can get the following lower and upper [tail bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) on the upper tail of the CDF of the binomial distribution (here, $K \gg np$):
   $$\begin{align} 
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 n}} \exp{\left(-n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel \frac{d}{n})\right)} \leq E[X_i] &= P[B_i\ge K] \leq \exp{\left(-n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel \frac{d}{n})\right)}
   \ \\
   \end{align} $$
4. Assuming $ n \gg K \gg d $ and using some calculus we get the following approximations and limits:
   $$\begin{align} 
   D(\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{n} \parallel \frac{d}{n}) &= \frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{n} \left(\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{d}\right) - 1\right) + \frac{d}{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} D(\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{n} \parallel \frac{d}{n}) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel p) = 0 \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel p) &= 
   \lim_{n \to \infty} K \log K + \mathcal{O}(K) = \infty \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left(-n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel p)\right) &= 0 \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\log n - K \log K + \mathcal{O}(K) &= \infty \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{2 n}} \exp\left(-n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel p)\right) &= 
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left(\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right) -n D(\frac{K}{n} \parallel p)\right) = 
   \infty \\
   \end{align} $$
   and with the bounds above we get:
   $$\begin{align}
   \lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_i] &= \lim_{n \to \infty} P[B_i\ge K] = 0 \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_x &= \lim_{n \to \infty} nE[X_i] = \infty \\
   \ \\
   \end{align} $$
5. Using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and the fact that $B_i^j,B_j^i,e_{ij}$ are independent random variables, approximate:
   $$\begin{align}
   E[X_i X_j] &= P[B_i\ge K , B_j\ge K] \\
   &= P[B_i\ge K \land B_j\ge K \| e_{ij}=1]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=1]} + P[B_i\ge K \land B_j\ge K \| e_{ij}=0]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=0]} \\
   &= P[B_i^j\ge K-1 \land B_j^i\ge K-1 \| e_{ij}=1]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=1]} + P[B_i^j\ge K \land B_j^i\ge K \| e_{ij}=0]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=0]} \\
   &= P[B_i^j\ge K-1 ]P[ B_j^i\ge K-1 ]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=1]} + P[B_i^j\ge K ]P[ B_j^i\ge K ]\color{brown}{P[e_{ij}=0]} \\
   &= P[B_i^j\ge K-1 ]P[ B_j^i\ge K-1 ]\color{brown}{p} + P[B_i^j\ge K ]P[ B_j^i\ge K ](\color{brown}{1-p}) \\
   &= P[B_i\ge K ]^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) \color{brown}{p} + P[B_i\ge K ]^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) (\color{brown}{1-p}) \\
   &= P[B_i\ge K ]^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) ( \color{brown}{p}+\color{brown}{1-p}) \\
   &= E[X_i]^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0 \\
   \ 
   \end{align}$$
6. Approximate the second moment:
   $$\begin{align}
   E[X^2] &= E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})^2] \\
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} E[X_{i}^2] + \sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^{n} E[X_{i}X_{j}] \\
   &= nE[X_{i}] + \sum_{i,j=1\\i\neq j}^{n} E[X_{i}X_{j}] \\
   &= \mu_x  + n (n-1) E[X_{i}X_{j}] \\
   &= \mu_x  + n^2 E[X_i]^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) \\
   &= \mu_x  + \mu_x^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1)) \\
   \end{align}$$
7. Using the [second moment method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_method):
   $$\begin{align}
   P[X \ge 1] & \geq \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]} \\
   &= \frac{\mu_x^2}{\mu_x  + \mu_x^2 (1+\mathcal{o}(1))} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty \implies \mu_x \to\infty]{} 1 \\
   \ 
   \end{align}$$
8. With high probability, at least one vertex with such degree exists.

Comment: Do not [repost the same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4597652/).  If you believe that one answer adequately addresses multiple questions, post *one* answer, and then flag the other question(s) for closure as duplicates.